# Program to check a web site address is valid or not

Tags: python, string, webaddress

I am writing a program that checks if a website has valid extension or not.
First I did this

```
website_address = 'facebook.com'
website_address.endswith('.com')
```

It works fine.
But I can check only one extension, so I thought to write a function that will check a list of extension.

```
def check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension(website_address):
    valid_extensions = ['.com', '.info', '.edu', '.org', '.biz', '.net']
    if website_address.endswith(valid_extensions):
        return 'check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension function returns True'
    else:
        return 'check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension functions returns False'
```

But when I call this function `check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension(website_address)` I get error

```
if website_address.endswith(valid_extensions):
TypeError: endswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not list
```

I write the program right, but I don't know by mistake.
Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, you are doing good. The only problem here is `str.endswith` function either takes a string or a tuple of string. Just change your list of valid extensions to tuple, It should work fine.

```py
valid_extensions = ('.com', '.info', '.edu', '.org', '.biz', '.net')
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**:

```py
>>> check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension('facebook.com')
 'check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension function returns True'

>>> check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension('google.net')
 'check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension function returns True'

>>> check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension('Hello')
 'check_if_website_address_is_valid_by_extension functions returns False'
```

One suggestion though, instead of returning such a long string, why don't you just `return` `True` or `False` Boolean value?